# Multiplying each column of a d x n matrix with each column of a 1 x n vector

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a `1 x 5` vector:

```
vect = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

and I have a `2 x 5` matrix:

```
mat = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
])
```

and I would like to multiply together as so: `10 * [[1], [6]] = [[10], [60]]` for each column in the vector and each column in the matrix, outputting a `d x n` vector. How can I efficiently accomplish this with `numpy`? I have tried to investigate dot product, but it doesn't seem to accomplish my goals.

Comment: `mat * vect` ? .

Comment: Or `np.multiply`

Comment: `vect` is actually 1d, shape (5,).  By broadcasting rules that's equivalent to a (1,5) array, which pairs nicely with the (2,5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vect * mat` does what you want, column-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

A*B should do it

```
import numpy as np
A = 10*(np.arange(5)+1)
B = (np.arange(10)+1).reshape([2,5])
assert (A*B == np.array([[ 10,  40,  90, 160, 250],
       [ 60, 140, 240, 360, 500]])).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @John Zwinck's answer, if your idea is to multiply `vect` 1st column to `mat` first column and so on, `vect * mat` will be enough. On the other hand, if you have a second thought of using every column in `vect` to multiply with every column in `mat`, you can use `numpy.tensordot`.

```
np.tensordot(vect,mat,axes=0)

Out[15]: 
array([[[ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50],
        [ 60,  70,  80,  90, 100]],

       [[ 20,  40,  60,  80, 100],
        [120, 140, 160, 180, 200]],

       [[ 30,  60,  90, 120, 150],
        [180, 210, 240, 270, 300]],

       [[ 40,  80, 120, 160, 200],
        [240, 280, 320, 360, 400]],

       [[ 50, 100, 150, 200, 250],
        [300, 350, 400, 450, 500]]])
```